# Is it possible to use the dot command in visual block mode?

Tags: vim

I have this text:

```
a     .55
b       .23
c    .12
d      .45
```

And I want to align the second column, to have this:

```
a    .55
b    .23
c    .12
d    .45
```

My first try was to put cursor in the first line, at the column where I want to align the text and press <kbd>dt.</kbd>, and later pressing <kbd>j</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> I can repeat it for all the lines, but since I have a lot of lines, I want to make a visual block and repeat the action for all the lines, is it possible to repeat a command in visual block mode? If not, which are the alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For all things aligning you probably want to use specialized plugins, e.g. [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) or [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294).

If you don't want to use plugins, I see 2 other possibilities:

*1)*

- mark lines in visual line mode (<kbd>V</kbd>)
- `:normal 5ldt.`

*2)*

- mark lines in visual line mode (<kbd>V</kbd>)
- `:s/\w\zs\s\+\ze\./     /`

Answer (score 3):

With my [visualrepeat plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3848), you can do this: After modifying the first line with `dt.`, select the following lines in *linewise* visual mode `Vjj`, move the cursor to the column where you want to repeat `4l`, and repeat `.`.

<sup>(Though I agree with mhinz that an alignment plugin is preferable in this particular case.)</sup>